# Cannot import java classes under src/main/java into src/test/java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am using maven project in Eclipse, where I am not able to access classes under src/main/java in src/test/java class. I could use the classes in maven dependacies jars though. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found that sometimes this error appears and by simply going `Project -> Clean...` the error will stop.

However if this does not work there is a blog with some more suggestions [here](http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207)

**Updated 11/07/2017**

The original link is no longer available, refer to web archive [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160808194301/http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=207)

Or just have them all here..

- ‘Clean’ Your Eclipse Project: Go to Project > Clean in Eclipse [This seems to work for me]
- Refresh your project folder (right click on your project > refresh)
- Re-build your project
- Clean your builds (If using Ant or Maven – clean your builds)
- Recreate your project in Eclipse
- ‘Switch’ Workspace – then Switch back (Eg Change to Debug, then switch back to Java)
- Remove and re-add your JRE:

  1. Right Click on your project > properties
  2. Click on the Libraries tab
  3. Click on the JRE
  4. Click remove, then OK
  5. Repeat 1-3 again, but add the JRE again

Comment: Thank you, I couldnt believe this worked. I had done a maven clean and rebuilt the dependancies and it did not work. An eclipse clean worked :o

Comment: I'm using eclipse 2019 - 12: switching Workspace then switching back did the trick for me.  Thumbs Up.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `import` them. Eclipse should help you with this: if you try to use the class names, it'll suggest where to import from.

The test classes are a separate package, so the classes will need to be declared `public`.

Comment: Thats exactly my question, I cannot import them. The import line shows class cannot be resolved

Comment: And they're part of the same project? Are the classes `public`?

Comment: Yes part of same project and are public classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, one can do it..

First You need to navigate to Build Path-->Configure Build Path--> Source tab

then in the Source tab search/check [your Project Name]/src/main/java and change

"contains test sources" from No to Yes and save it.

This will resolved issue of import packages from "src/test/java" to "src/main/java" successfully

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening because my IntelliJ Idea was configured for a different JDK version and my terminal was referring to a different JDK version. Due to this whenever I run Maven clean from the terminal, and then try to run tests via IDE, it gives this error.

Answer (score -1):

Project -> Clean

is enough for me to work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has already been answered and accepted, no need to add the same answer again.